# Android, Storing and retrieving Text

Tags: java, android, xml, database, tree

I'm currently working on an Android application for my college, let me give you a swift presentation:

There is a story which the player can read, and then he will have 3 choices, he will choose one, and another story will show up with 3 choices again and so it goes on... (But every choice lead to a complete different story)

As you can guess, i have a lot of text to store, to class and to retrieve. The first page shows the first story and 3 choices, if the player chooses and clicks on a button, the following story will appear but it can also mean the end (obviously if i always keep 3 paths X 3 paths X 3 paths... it's going to get complicated)

_______________ What I was thinking about ____________________________

So my first guess was to use an xml file, one with every story and another with every choice.

At the opening of the application, i would use a parser to run through the file and put every string in a Tree Structure. (so one tree for the stories and another for choices I suppose)

I wanted to use number to structure it, for exemple, if you are currently on 1 and you click on choice 2 then you put another 2 at the end of the previous story, it will become 12, and then if you click on choice 3, it become 123 etc...
I though it was easier for the tree, alas, xml only give a tag name so i wanted to use story1, story11, story12, story13 etc...

[What the structure of my xml should look like (or my tree)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4QkA.png)

But it's already bothering to class it in a tree since i wanted to use numbers, I have to get a String with parser.parName(), and then I need to substring to get the number at the end,  and just to retrieve in what node it should go take some ressources.

In other means, the more I think about it, the more I come up with complicated ideas, so I need some smart people to tell me where to go. (I have clearly lost myself on the road)

__________________________________  My question ____________________________

If you feel like this smart one, here is my question

What would you use to store the text? an Xml file? would you use a tree after that? And how would you do that, to efficiently class the xml into the Tree?

I can see that my explanation is a bit messy, so please tell me if they are something you don't understand. (or if it is my broken english)

Thanks for answering !

Comment: Hm. Interesting question. Let me ask you this: Are the paths absolute? Like do the same choices always lead down the same path? Or can stories and choices intermingle with one another? Like could I be 5 levels deep in story 1 and then get choice 33 as one of my choices? If not, I think JSON could work pretty well to build this structure.

Comment: Well I was thinking to keep the paths absolute and not intermingle but I have to admit that you raise an interesting point, it could spare me a lot of ressources to lead to another branch of the tree. But I would have to return a value that telling me where to go since it will go on a completely different part of the tree. I do not know JSON, I will try to see that, thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking through this question a bit, I basically came up with a similar idea to Kenny Byun's answer, but I'd like to flesh it out with some actual code to show you how it would work.

First of all, I would store each individual story in its own JSON object. I don't know that they would need to be in separate files as Kenny suggested, as they could just as easily be contained in separate objects in a JSON array in a single file. The structure would be as follows.

Each object in the array would be a "story" object. This contains an index or some sort of id to identify it as a unique story. It then contains its story text, and an array of 3 "choice" objects. The choice objects are similar in that they each contain an id or index, some text, and a "leads_to_story" value, which basically identifies which story this choice leads to. It would look something like this...

```
[
    {
        "story_index" : 0,
        "story_text" : "It was a dark and stormy night. Three doors stand before you. You must choose one.",
        "choices" : [
            {
                "choice_index" : 0,
                "choice_text" : "Door 1",
                "leads_to_story" : 1 
            },
            {
                "choice_index" : 1,
                "choice_text" : "Door 2",
                "leads_to_story" : 2
            },
            {
                "choice_index" : 2,
                "choice_text" : "Door 3",
                "leads_to_story" : 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "story_index" : 1,
        "story_text" : "You choose door 1 and enter cautiously. You find a bunny rabbit.",
        "choices" : [
            {
                "choice_index" : 0,
                "choice_text" : "Pet the bunny rabbit.",
                "leads_to_story" : 4 
            },
            {
                "choice_index" : 1,
                "choice_text" : "Kill the bunny rabbit.",
                "leads_to_story" : 5
            },
            {
                "choice_index" : 2,
                "choice_text" : "Ask the bunny rabbit its name.",
                "leads_to_story" : 6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now that you have all your story and choice data stored in an organized way, I would create two classes to store this data for access during runtime. So I would create a Story class, and a Choice class. They might look something like this...

```
public class Story {
    public int index;
    public String text;
    public Choice[] choices;

    public Story(int index, String text, Choice[] choices) {
        this.index = index;
        this.text = text;
        this.choices = choices;
    }
}

public class Choice {
    public String text;
    public int leads_to_story;

    public Choice(String text, int leads_to_story) {
        this.text = text;
        this.leads_to_story = leads_to_story;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to load all your story data into organized objects, which could then be accessed from an array of Story objects that are placed in numerical order. So when you need a certain Story, you just call that index from the Array. Your workflow might look something like this...

```
//if this is a new game...

//Load and parse the JSON into a local array,
//placing the stories in numerical order
ArrayList<Story> stories = getStories();

//Present story 0, since this is a new game...
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_text);
Story story = stories.get(0); 
String storyText = story.text;
textView.setText(storyText);

//The player makes his choice, so you now
//get the leads_to_story value to find out
//where to go next...
int playerChoice = 1; //whatever they choose
int nextStory = story.choices[playerChoice].leads_to_story;

//New screen loads or is initialized,
//and we load the new story...
Story story = stories.get(nextStory);
//...repeat the process...
```

For a "death" scenario, I would probably just have a story object with index -1 or something like that. So then you could just always test if the `leads_to_story < 0` and know if the player died.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas of how to keep things manageable and organized. In these types of scenarios, I'm always tempted to try and find the "clever" way of handling the data, but more often than not, a simple, practical approach works much better and keeps things much more readable and manageable. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would put each scenario in one JSON file each and each choice has a key that points to the next filename if there's no need to translate any of your assets. You can load the first file (or last save) at runtime. The file name of the scenario would be the "save" itself.

However, if you need translation for any of your story lines, you may want to dump it in "strings.xml" and then create the tree at runtime with references to the respective R.string ids. The R.string id should not be used as a save in this case however, as it can change between compilations. Each story scenario should probably have a scenario ID that should never be modified (an enum would do it)